# Cup product on the torus, $\alpha \cup \alpha \neq 0$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to compute the cup product on the Torus. But somehow my calculation is wrong and I cannot figure out why.

We give $T^2$ the $\Delta$-complex structure as in the picture below:
($K,L$ are positively oriented, starting in the bottom left corner)

[image]

I computed the cohomology groups with integer coefficients to be
$$H^0=<x^*>, \qquad H^1=<A^*+C^*,B^*+C^* >, \qquad H^2=<K^*>,$$

where $^*$ denotes the dual, e.g. $A^*(A)=1, A^*(B)=0=A^*(C)$.

Due to the anti symmetry of the cup product, we have $$(A^*+C^*) \cup (A^*+C^*)=-(A^*+C^*) \cup (A^*+C^*),$$ so $$(A^*+C^*) \cup (A^*+C^*)=0.$$

But if I compute it explicitly, I get
$$(A^*+C^*) \cup (A^*+C^*) (K)= (A^*+C^*)(C) * (A^*+C^*)(-A)=-1,\\
(A^*+C^*) \cup (A^*+C^*) (L)= (A^*+C^*)(A) * (A^*+C^*)~(B)~~~=~~~0,$$

so $(A^*+C^*) \cup (A^*+C^*)$ evaluated on the cycle $K+L$ does not vanish.

This is the wrong result, but I have no clue where I made a mistake. I would appreciate some help.

---

As A.Rod pointed out, there are ways to parametrize $K$ and $L$ in which the computation yields the right result. For example $K,L$ positively oriented, L starting at the bottom left but K starting at the top right.
However, I don't see any reason why this should depend on the parametrization.

Comment: Your description of the cohomology is wrong. $C=A+B$ in the $H_1$ so how can $A^*(C)$ be $0$. The $H_1$ has rank $2$ and is generated by $A^*$ and $B^*$, $((A^*+C^*), (B^*+C^*))$ is not a basis and in any case you cannot have the relations you mention between the $A,B,C$ and $A^*, B^*, C^*$ cannot be true otherwise the rank of the $H^1$ would be at least 3.

Comment: I was thinking about $A^*$ as a map from the chains to $\mathbb{Z}$, not on homology.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the way you ordered the vertices. Especially I don't see how can $K+L$ being closed be consistant with your computation of the 1st cup product. If you order the vertices of the square anti-clockwise say starting from the bottom left corner, everything seems to works out fine.

Comment: Also, you do realize that the graded comutativity of the cup product is true in cohomology and not necessarily as cochains. It does not mean that $a\cup a=0$ in your case, it only means that $\alpha\cup \alpha=ds$ for $s$ a 1-cochain.

Comment: Could you provide a detailled computation, because I really dont see how "everything works out fine"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the original answer was never corrected, I will answer the question myself.

My mistake was, that I did not use a valid $\Delta$-complex structure. For some reason it is mentioned, but not really emphasized in Hatcher's book, that such a structure is more than simply drawing some triangles.

Take a look at the two "$\Delta$-complexes" below. The left one is the one used in the question.
[image]
The left structure has two 2-simplices $[v_0, v_1, v_2]$ and $[w_0, w_1, w_2]$. These have the faces $[v_0, v_1],~ [v_1,v_2],~ [v_0,v_2]$ and $[w_0, w_1]~,[w_1, w_2],~ [w_0,w_2]$.
The picture says how these faces have to be identified. In particular, considering $A$, we have to identify $[v_0,v_1]$ with $[w_2, w_1]$. But $[w_2, w_1]$ is not a face! Thus this is not a valid $\Delta$-complex structure.

The right picture however describes a $\Delta$-complex, as it has the faces $$[v_0,v_1] \sim [w_1, w_2] ~(A)\\
[v_1,v_2] \sim [w_0, w_1] ~(B)\\
[v_0,v_2] \sim [w_0, w_2] ~ (C)$$

---

Computing the cohomology groups one gets
$$H^0=<x^*>, ~~~ H^1=<A^*+C^*, B^*+C^*> ~~~H^2=<K^*,L^*|K^*-L^*>$$
and $K+L$ is a $2$-cycle.

Further, 
$$(A^*+C^* \cup A^*+C^*)(K) = (A^*+C^*) (B) (A^*+C^*)(A)=0 \\
(A^*+C^* \cup A^*+C^*)(L) =(A^*+C^*)(A) (A^*+C^*)(B) =0$$
So $(A^*+C^* \cup A^*+C^*)(K+L) =0$. Similarly one gets $(A^*+B^* \cup A^*+B^*)(K+L) =0$.

One couldthink that this result only holds, because everything in the calculation above vanishes. However, changing the basis of $H^1$ to $H^1=<A^*-B^*,A^*+C^*>$ still gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

View your square as (the convex hull of) $s_0=(0,0),s_1=(0,1), s_2=(1,1), s_3=(1,0)$. The orientation on $A=[s_0, s_1]$, $B=[s_1, s_2]$ and $C=[s_0, s_2]$ is given by the order of the vertices and $K$ will be ordered as $[s_0, s_1, s_2]$ and $L$ as $[s_2, s_3, s_0]$.
This way you have $\partial K=B-C+A$ and $\partial L=-B+C-A$, thus $K+L$ is closed.
In the same way $(A^*+C^*)(\partial K)=(A^*+C^*)(\partial L)=0$ and $A^*+C^*$ is closed.

Now $$(A^*+C^*)\cup(A^*+C^*)(K+L)=(A^*+C^*)(A)(A^*+C^*)(B)+(A^*+C^*)(-A)(A^*+C^*)(-B)=0$$
and $$(B^*+C^*)\cup(B^*+C^*)(K+L)=(B^*+C^*)(A)(B^*+C^*)(B)+(B^*+C^*)(-A)(B^*+C^*)(-B)=0$$
Of course I may have made a mistake in my computation.

Comment: This seems to be the right answer, but I am still as confused as before. To me it seems like you chose the simplex structure in one of the few ways which lead to the right result.  
According to my understadning, if we define $L$ as $[s_0, s_2, s_3]$ instead of $[s_2, s_3, s_0]$, nothing should change.  
But then the first cup product does not vanish.

Comment: I see the problem. In fact it is also a mistake I made in my answer even though my computation works "by accident".
This is both a bit subtle and blatantly obvious and this comes from the fact that you're doing your computations on chains rather that directly on cohomology.
The problem is that neither my $K+L$ nor your $K+L$ are closed. To check that they're closed you need to check that $\partial(K+L)=0$ as a chain. But as chains it is wrong that $[s_0, s_1]=-[s_1, s_0]$ this is only true if you look at their image in the $H_1$.

Comment: To have a genuinely closed chain you need to take $K-L$ with appropriate orientations. $K+L$ will never be closed whichever orientation you choose on the vertices because the augmentation map will always take $\partial (K+L)$ to $2$.

Comment: I apologize for my "answer" who was thus wrong. I'll make changes accordingly.